# Cat command output varies unusually in regards to * character

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cat, ssh-keys, globbing

I'm running the following command on a fairly standard Ubuntu 11.04 installation running under vSphere:

```
sudo cat /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Basically, I am using puppet for ssh key management and wanted to ensure the keys were present. What is unusual about this simple command is that the keys are only shown for two users (the first and third user created on the user if that is relevant) when the * should catch something like 7 or 8 users' homes.

The intriguing part is that, if I run

```
sudo cat /home/user.name/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

where user.name is the name of a random user (not one of the two that already show), not only do I get the correct output from cat, but the next time I run

```
sudo cat /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

the output shows 3 key files! Two files for the two users previously shown and a third file that is the user whose key file I just manually looked at.

I can continue to play this "game", and each time I manually specify a user and then run the * command, that previously viewed user shows up in the globbed output. To me, this is unusual behavior, especially for a bog-standard Ubuntu image. Is there something I am missing? Special properties of * expansion or cat?

Edit: Forgot to mention that this behavior "resets" if I leave the ssh session to the server. By that I mean that I can logout and log back in via SSH, and I am back to the starting conditions (only two user accounts are shown with *).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the command line is parsed and wildcards are replaced **BEFORE** it is executed.

If you specify the username, then the sudo ... command can see the file because it's accessing it as root.

When you type '*', your USER shell expands that to the paths **it can see**, well... the paths which allow your current user to search the subdirectories.

You might try enclosing the path string in SINGLE quotes to prevent expansion, I'm not sure that'll work since most unix programs expect the shell to expand wildcards and thus don't perform the globbing action themselves.

EDIT:  A thought about how to accomplish your goal of reading the authorized keys files for all the users:

```
sudo find /home -name "authorized_keys" -exec cat "{}" \; > all_the_data
```

Maybe crude, but it'll work since you're executing the file search as root, not your user.

I suppose another way:

```
sudo 'find /home -name "authorized_keys" -print0 | xargs -0 cat' > all_the_data
```

That one's nicer on the process count, since it accumulates all the filenames and then 'cat's them... but I like the first one, no special quoting required.

The quotes (single or otherwise) around the entire command are required because of the pipe command.  both the find and xargs command MUST be executed as root.  Yeah, more complicated than the first one.

Comment: Your explanation of the reason for the strange globbing behavior is brilliant, +1, but I'm not entirely convinced. Why does the `sudo cat /home/user.name/.ssh/authorized_keys` command have the **lasting side effect** of affecting the output of subsequent commands containing the glob, when the glob command isn't able to see the contents prior to that direct cat? Is it because the shell caches the files it sees in there?

Comment: Okay, the 1st solution is within my knowledge of find. And I was about to ask you why the one user _would_ show up (using *) while others wouldn't but I just discovered that the ssh folder for that user is 755 as opposed to the others that are 700.

Comment: Add.: It just seems odd to me that `look at some files that only root can see;` followed by `look at files that my user can see` results in the latter command "knowing" about the directory structure by virtue of the former command successfully stating that directory. **Especially** since the "direct" (non-globbed) method doesn't involve ANY shell expansion whatsoever, so the **shell** is not finding that directory; the `cat` command is! Within a sudo instance at that!!!

Comment: I can't explain the lasting side effect, although since it 'resets' when you log off, it might be related to the sudo window.  That period of time during which sudo will let you do things before the permissions run out again.  Usually like 5 minutes or 15 minutes from the LAST valid sudo you executed.

Comment: Based on Richard's explanation of the permissions, now I understand why the heisenbug with only some of the users displaying. This solves the mystery so we don't have to go wondering about bash examining the `fstat()` syscalls of its child processes to learn about directories it's aware of. o_O

Comment: Exactly.  My answer did involve permissions, I just beat around the bush the long way... Thanks for the help @allquixotic

Comment: Help?!?! I learned something! That's the best part of participating in this discussion! :) Thank YOU!

Comment: Okay so the permission issue explained why I always get the one additional user. And I just tested the * command with a sudo -K (to reset the timestamp) and that is indeed the solution for the second part. The "lasting" side-effect is due to the sudo time window. Interesting info, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct explanation for why the globbing is doing what it's doing, but I know how you can rewrite your script to accomplish what you want:

> for i in /home/*; do if [ -d "/home/${i}" ]; then sudo cat "/home/${i}/.ssh/authorized_keys"; fi; done

I don't know of any feature of bash that would cause it to glob differently depending on past commands run, so it may either be a bug or a really deeply buried (undocumented) feature. I NEVER use globs for directories; I always use either the find command for a for loop. I don't trust globs to do the right thing with any pattern containing `/*/`.